# regular expression to check for a blank value in the given input text

Tags: regex

Here is the data that I use as input

```
TEXT = "*** This is for test \"ABC_DEF/ghi_JKL\"U 1234 5678\nThis is also for test\n\nTEST\n\nDEMO TEST\n\nDEM             ABC                      DEF                      GHI\nCASE-0     192.168.1.0   192.168.1.1     192.168.1.2\n\nJKL          MNO               PQR           STU\n             111                                              222\nEND\n-TestCase(HIP)=MAXPAYNE3\n-GameType(RPG)=SERIOUS SAM3\n"
```

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
if(match($NV_SPECIFIC_PROBLEM, "CP AP COMMUNICATION FAULT")) {
  de= extract($TEXT, ".*DEF.*?\n\s*(\S+)\s+")
  a = extract($TEXT, ".*DEF.*?\n\s*\S+\s+(\S+)\s+")
  d = extract($TEXT, ".*DEF.*?\n\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+")
  g = extract($TEXT, ".*DEF.*?\n\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s*")

  j = extract($TEXT, ".*STU\n\s*(\S+)\s+")
  m = extract($TEXT, ".*STU\n\s*\S+\s+(\S+)\s+")
  p = extract($TEXT, ".*STU\n\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+")
  s = extract($TEXT, ".*STU\n\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s*")

  $OUTPUT = "DEM=" + $de + " ABC=" + $a + " DEF=" + $d + " GHI=" + $g + ", JKL=" + $j + ", MNO= " + m + ", PQR=" + p + ", STU=" + $s 
  update(@OUTPUT)
}
```

This code gives this output:

```
DEM=CASE-0, ABC=192.168.1.0, DEF=192.168.1.1, GHI=192.168.1.2, JKL=, MNO=111, PQR=, STU=222
```

But I want output as follows:

```
DEM=CASE-0, ABC=192.168.1.0, DEF=192.168.1.1, GHI=192.168.1.2, MNO=111, STU=222
```

Comment: You forgot to mention your problem.

Comment: You can do a match against ^\s*$; a match means the string is "empty"

Comment: @phresnel the actual code gives output as **DEM=CASE-0, ABC=192.168.1.0, DEF=192.168.1.1, GHI=192.168.1.2, JKL=, MNO=111, PQR=, STU=222** But i want output as **DEM=CASE-0, ABC=192.168.1.0, DEF=192.168.1.1, GHI=192.168.1.2, MNO=111, STU=222** where jkl and pqr should not present

Comment: Okay, that's a problem statement. But what problem do you have solving it?

Comment: i need a regular expression which encounter blank value after stu as shown in input text above **\nJKL          MNO               PQR           STU\n**

Comment: @Lucky it works fine for first Encounter of blank value but it fails after encoutering blank value for **PQR**

Comment: @PavanDongray: Yeah, that's what you _need_; but what _exact problem_ are you having? Do you think you have an error in your regex? Do you think you have chosen the wrong matching function, and if so, what have you tried to find the right one? Have you read the FAQ at all?

Comment: @PavanDongray: And please mention which programming language you use.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

`$OUTPUT = "DEM=" + $de + " ABC=" + $a + " DEF=" + $d + " GHI=" + $g + ", JKL=" + $j + ", MNO= " + m + ", PQR=" + p + ", STU=" + $s`

You automaticaly put all names and insert the values. This: `j = extract($TEXT, ".*STU\n\s*(\S+)\s+")` does apparently return null or empty. You should add the `JKL=` only if the `j` is not empty. 
I'd advice to check if the value is not null, and than add it to your output.

Comment: @PavanDongray try the Empty() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php